# Why are bidirectional hashmap implementations rarely included in the standard library?

Tags: hashmap, standard-library, bidirectional

Every once in a while, I need to use a bidirectional hashmap. Independent of the programming language, bidirectional hashmaps seem to be rarely included in the standard library. Why? Is the group that regularly uses them simply too small?

Comment: Great question, although this _might_ be a better fit for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/